# MS Access SQL: Grouping By Month

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create an SQL query which returns the frequency of each month appearing in my table (in a percentage form).

The SQL i have written to start this is the following:

```
SELECT Format(Sum(IIf(Sale_PickupDateTime="*/01/*",1,0))/Count(Sale_PickupDateTime), "Percent") AS January
FROM [Sales Table];
```

I plan to continue onwards for each month.

My issue is that when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

"Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression."

I am fairly certain this happens because sale_pickupdatetime is a general date format because I have used this code elsewhere (Sale_reason is a text field):

```
SELECT Format(Sum(IIf(Sale_Reason="Business",1,0))/Count(Sale_Reason), "Percent") AS Business
FROM [Sales Table];
```

and it has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik Access supports a `MONTH` function:

```
SELECT
   Format(Sum(IIf(MONTH(Sale_PickupDateTime)=1,1,0))/Count(Sale_PickupDateTime)
         , "Percent") AS January
FROM [Sales Table];
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like:

```
Select 
    Format(Sale_PickupDateTime, "yyyymm") As Period,
    Format(Count(*)/DCount("*", "[Sales Table]"), "Percent") As MonthShare
From
    [Sales Table];
Group By
    Format(Sale_PickupDateTime, "yyyymm")
```